# How would I make a function and insert it into a table

Tags: lua, lua-table

I have a function that will create a function and insert that function in the table it somewhat goes like this.

```
local Events = {}
Events.Functions = {}

Events.AddEvent = function(code1)
    local Event = function(code1)
        loadstring(code1)
    end
    table.insert(Events.Functions, Event)
end

Events.AddEvent("print(\"hello\")")
```

Comment: `function Events.AddEvent(code) table.insert(Events.Functions, assert(loadstring(code))) end`

Answer (score 2):

`loadstring` (or `load` in Lua 5.2 or higher) itself returns a function, you don't need the extra `function` when defining `Event`:

```
local Event = loadstring(code1)
table.insert(Events.Functions, Event)
```

Or simply:

```
table.insert(Events.Functions, loadstring(code1))
```

Comment: Thanks for this, this is exactly what I needed, Cheers.

Comment: @lhf That's what I was thinking, but wrote it wrong :(, fixed now.